# First item in errors() is [null]

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following code:

```
function JobTask() {
    var self = this;

    self.description = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: true
    });
    self.priority = ko.observable('').extend({
        number: true,
        required: true
    });
    self.complete = ko.observable(false);
}

function CreateJobViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.task = ko.observable(new JobTask());

    self.taskErrors = ko.validation.group(self.task);
    self.addTask = function () {

        if (self.taskErrors().length) {
            console.log(self.taskErrors());
            self.taskErrors.showAllMessages();
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is, when I add a task, it is invalid for some reason even when I have entered in the fields correctly. The console outputs `[null]`. Upon further investigation, it seems that even when I don't enter my fields correctly, the first item in my `taskErrors` array is always `[null]`. So it may looks like: `[null], "This field is required."`. Not sure what I've done wrong?

### Edit

Here is a fiddle I created of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5kh6h/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the errors into the `JobTask` and the issue goes away.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/5kh6h/4/

--

```
function JobTask() {
    var self = this;

    self.description = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: true
    });
    self.priority = ko.observable('').extend({
        number: true,
        required: true
    });
    self.complete = ko.observable(false);
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);    
}

function CreateJobViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.task = ko.observable(new JobTask());

    self.addTask = function() {

        if (self.task().errors().length) {
            console.log(self.task().errors());
            self.task().errors.showAllMessages();
        }
        else {
            alert('Success!');
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle because the resources were not found, http://jsfiddle.net/robnardo/RSxfS/

Answer (score 5):

your task attribute is observable(a function), so to apply validation to it you should pass the object with ().

```
self.taskErrors = ko.validation.group(self.task());
```

You should be careful when your object is observable.

```
self.task = ko.observable(new JobTask());
```

You can acces to his attribute like this:

```
console.log(self.task().description);
```

Not like this :

```
console.log(self.task.description);
```

Task without () is a function not an object that's the trick.

Here's your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/5kh6h/5/

Good luck